Double-entry (GnuCash) tracking shared assets within a single bank account
I'm managing a bank account for a group of us. There is (say) $1,000 in the bank account (set up as a checking account under assets) - how should I manage the allocation of a quarter of the total to Alf, Bert, Charlie, and Dave?
I don't want any transactions in the bank-account - as there are none - but need to know that each of them 'owns' a quarter of it, and I can then any spend on behalf of one or more of them could be allocated appropriately...
Not sure whether I need to set up 'asset', 'equity' or 'liability' accounts for ABC+D...
I would then like to recognise any bank-account payments appropriately split between those relevant... so I know a) how much the bank balance should be, and b) how much is 'owned' by A, B, C & D.
Slowly getting my head around this double-entry stuff...!
Thanks!

I don't know if GnuCash supports this. What makes you think it does?

I had kind of assumed that any proper double-entry system should be able to account for managing monies allocated effectively to budgets, and allow transactions on bank account to be associated with those 'budgets' or 'allocations'... I thought it was my (tenuous) grip on Double Entry Principles which was letting me down - but maybe GnuCash doesn't have the necessary double-entry features that other 'grown up' double-entry packages (Sage/quickbooks/Xero)... That's why I'm trying to learn :-)

budgets and double entry are completely unrelated principles. GnuCash supports budgets somewhat, but I'm not sure if that's actually what you need here - you're talking about equity allocation per transaction. Generally, that's not needed in a regular accounting AFAIK, so I doubt GnuCash would support that

Sounds like you want to operate a loan tied to a bank account. This would be way too much work to have 2 x double entry transactions on each transaction with a manual balance.
As an alternative, just tag each transaction with a share to each person. So a deposit into the cheque account would be four $250 splits tagged Alf, Bert, Charlie, and Dave. Tag the expenses as appropriate.
You can run reports filtered by the tags. Alternatively, run the custom report from https://github.com/dawansv/gnucash-custom-reports#examples

Accounting newbie here but I would do as follows:

Under the 'Asset:BankAccount' account that maps the "physical" bank account, I would create four sub-accounts 'Asset:BankAccount:[Person]Share', where [Person] is A/B/C/D.
I would add four transactions to fill the bank account (or a single transaction with four splits). Each transaction would credit 'Income:[Person]Contribution' account with $1000/4 and debit 'Asset:BankAccount:[Person]Share'
Whenever there are expenses you can debit 'Expense:' account and credit each 'Asset:BankAccount:[Person]Share' account with one-fourth of the expense (using splits).


A basic point is that (IIUC) only transactions affect account balances in double accounting. So you do need transactions to fill the bank account, and you need transactions to track contributions/expenses as time goes on.
Moreover not all accounting transactions or accounts needs to have an immediate physical mapping.

I don't think this is a good fit for OPs issue. If you do it like that, the transactions of Asset:BankAccount do not match the transactions of the physical account.

I could he a single transaction with four splits.
